# columns to rows hibernate

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, hibernate

I have tables called PATIENTINFO and MEDICATIONINFO with columns as mentioned below

```
PATIENTINFO

PatiendId      Disease
------------------------
1000            Fever
1001            Cold


MEDICATIONINFO

MedId     PatiendId    Medicine     Value    Reaction
------------------------------------------------------
100         1000         Med1        100       R
101         1000         Med2        200       L
102         1000         Med3        150       H
103         1001         Med1        120       L
104         1001         Med2        150       R
105         1001         Med3        300       H
```

I want result to be in the below format (Hibernate query)

```
Medicine    Value1     Reaction1     Value2     Reaction2 .......(Value n ...Reaction n)  
----------------------------------------------------------------
Med1            100           R       120          L
Med2            200           L       150          R
Med3            150           H       300          H
```

Can anyone help me out in this??

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: This kind of thing is called a 'pivot' query.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT
    MINFO.Medicine,
    MINFO.Reaction1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MINFO.Reaction = 'R' THEN Value ELSE 0 END) Value1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MINFO.Reaction = 'L' THEN Value ELSE 0 END) Value2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MINFO.Reaction = 'H' THEN Value ELSE 0 END) Value3,
FROM PATIENTINFO PINFO
    LEFT JOIN MEDICATIONINFO MINFO
        ON PINFO.PatiendId  = MINFO.PatiendId
GROUP BY MINFO.Reaction
```